# Connecting Java sockets over wifi?

Tags: java, networking

I am trying to make a simple messaging program using javafx and the java.net package. Right now I have a client class and server class that connect using serversocket and client socket on a random port. It works if I run both on the same computer or run them on different computers as long as both are connected to the same wifi and I specify the ip address.

However, it does not work if the two computers are not connected to the same wifi. How do I make it so that it works? Sorry, I am new to java.net and networking.

Comment: Okay I am sorry but that question and the hits on google involve communication over a lan network which my code already works for. I need to know how to communicate over a wan network where computers are connected through different routers and isp's. I suspect maybe some security issue but I am not sure how to fix that. Sorry if that was not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [traverse the NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) of your router.
This can be done in one of the following ways:

If the router supports it, you could use a UPnP library like [this one](https://github.com/4thline/cling).
UPnP basically asks the router to be allowed to talk to the outside network on a port.

However as not all routers support UPnP, you can try a Port punching protocol like [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), there are [libraries](https://github.com/tking/JSTUN) for java available.

If this does not work, you need to relay the network traffic through your own servers, with a protocol like [TURN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT).

There is the ICE protocol, which combines the former 2 protocols.
In java this can be done with libraries like [ICE4J](https://github.com/jitsi/ice4j).

Comment: Oh, doing port forwarding on my router worked. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @albert-jin if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.